# Find with or operators

Tags: linux, bash, find

I've a bash command who should find and remove files:

```
/usr/bin/find /srv/www/vest2/produktion/ -type f \( -iname 'vest*.xml' -o -iname 'vest*.xls'-o -iname 'vwk*.xls' \) -ctime +90 -exec rm {} \ ';'
```

but it doesn't work.
Whats the problem?

Many thanks
Martin

Comment: The problem is that "it doesn't work" doesn't work as an error description.

Comment: what's the issue? did you tried using -delete option?

Comment: Backslashes on the parenthesis, why? Semicolon at the end in `''`, why? Observed behaviour, expected behaviour? Try the `find` without the `-exec` part to check which files are found. Try removing the backslashes and the `''` mentioned above. See how it changes the outcome. *Post the error message if you're getting one.*

Comment: DevSolar: There are no errors but the files aren't removed.

Comment: Have you verified that there *are* matching files in `/srv/www/vest2/produktion/`? Can you show us? Do you have permission to delete them? *Why are you testing a broken find-remove against a "production" directory?*

Comment: One of this 3 files are found: vest2.xls, vest2.xml (found), vest3.xls. I've tried whithout -ctime and exec. The permissions are ok.

Comment: As long as I'm writing the line as you did, the `';'` at the end gives me "missing argument for -exec" (so much for "no error"). Writing `\;` instead, the command works.

Comment: @DevSolar using `';'` is perfectly fine and the parenths need backslashing, for the way you are talking to OP i would expect you to actually understand the find command.@Martin the backslash with the space after before the end will cause the "missing argument for -exec" error though.... Use either `\;` or `';'`, not a mix of both

Comment: DevSolar. Yes the command is working but the files in the \(..) section are still exist.

Comment: If the command were working, the files would be deleted, now would they? Please try: 1) The find command up to (and including) `\)` -- does it list all three files? (It should.) 2) The find command up to (and including) `-ctime +90` -- does it list all three files? (Completely depends on their last status change, and if they don't match the `-ctime` constraint, they won't be deleted obviously.) Note that SMA (correctly) pointed out that `find` has a builtin action to delete found files, `-delete` (instead of `-exec rm {} \;`).

Comment: @MartinBachtold Please fix the spacing in your question. It's impossible to tell where your errors are coming from if we don't know what your original command is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around the final semi colon

Before:

```
/usr/bin/find /srv/www/vest2/produktion/ -type f \( -iname 'vest*.xml' -o -iname 'vest*.xls'-o -iname 'vwk*.xls' \) -ctime +90 -exec rm {} \ ';'
/usr/bin/find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Now:

```
/usr/bin/find /srv/www/vest2/produktion/ -type f \( -iname 'vest*.xml' -o -iname 'vest*.xls'-o -iname 'vwk*.xls' \) -ctime +90 -exec rm {} \;
/usr/bin/find: `/srv/www/vest2/produktion/': No such file or directory
```

If that directory existed for me, it would have executed.